# Custom Cart Price Rule Actions in Magento 2.2 (Trigger somewhen when a coupon code is redeemd)

Tags: magento2, coupon

Is it possible to add custom actions for coupon codes?

e.g You're on the cart page and have been provided with a coupon code, when you enter the coupon code it adds x1 Burger to your basket.

or You enter a coupon code which hits an external API triggering a webhook to start a process.

Basically we'd like to trigger a custom class/method when this type of coupon is redeemed, rather than the default ones.

Is this supported and/or possible?

*note* - NOT a custom rule, a custom action :)

Thanks

Comment: Hi. Any update on this?

Comment: Nope, nobody gave any responses, and I asked on Magentos github and they just closed and ignored the issue

Comment: The Magento GitHub is only for reporting bugs, so that's why they closed your issue. This is definitely possible, as evidenced by the fact that there are third party extensions that add custom actions. I need to do this myself and will try to post an answer here when I figure it out (I haven't started yet).